# How to convert DITA xml to CQ xml?

Tags: xml, aem, dita, dita-ot

We are working on a migration project to migrate content from Drupal to AEM using DITA xml files. 
Currently, there's a task to explore how AEM consumes the metadata contained in these xml files. 
Mainly, there's a need to add page properties in a ditamap. This, however, is not to be done manually (via page properties tags in AEM), which is why, we have to come up with a way to add cq:tag attribute somehow in the ditamap xml file. This is to ensure that page properties are directly consumed by AEM when the ditamap is uploaded and converted to an AEM Site.
I have tried some options given here-Adobe CQ Help | Migrating DITA XML data to Adobe CQ , but, to no avail.

Can someone help me with the syntax, if at all the inclusion of cq:tag inside a ditamap is possible.

P.S. : The metadata structure currently has these type of tags in the ditamap-
   (Encrypted as per policy)
But, these are not being read by AEM. So, in a way, we are expecting if there's any modification possible to accommodate such content in AEM via these dita xml files.

Thanks,
Sonakshi S.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking. If you know the DITA input and the XML output you want to create from it, then we can certainly help you write the XSLT code to do the conversion. On the other hand if you don't know exactly what XML you need to create, then that requires more specialist knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the **Installation and Configuration Guide** for the XML Documentation Add-on, available at https://helpx.adobe.com/support/xml-documentation-for-experience-manager.html.  This document has a section titled "Customize DITA element mapping with AEM components" that outlines the following:

> DITA elements in the XML Documentation solution are mapped to their
> corresponding AEM compo-nents. The XML Documentation solution uses
> this mapping in workflows such as publishing and review to convert
> DITA element to a corresponding AEM component. The mapping is defined
> in the elementmapping.xml file, which can be accessed from the CRXDE
> Lite mode. Access the following URL in the CRXDE Lite
> mode:
>
> /libs/fmdita/config/elementmapping.xml
>
> **NOTE**: Do not make any
> customizations in the default configuration files available in the
> libs node. You must create an overlay of the libs node in the apps
> node and update the required files in the appsnode only.You may use
> the predefined DITA element mappings, or you can map DITA elements to
> your custom AEM components. To use your custom AEM components, you
> need to understand the structure of the elementmapping.xml file.

The documentation file and the elementmapping.xml file show examples of how elements from the source DITA file can be mapped to page or component properties.

As to getting the metadata into the source DITA files, this could be done by adding a `meta` element to the `prolog`, and the `meta` element can have `othermeta` elements for custom metadata such as the tag values you want to consume.  See https://docs.oasis-open.org/dita/v1.1/OS/langspec/langref/metadata.html and https://docs.oasis-open.org/dita/v1.1/OS/langspec/langref/othermeta.html.